# Implementing websocket support for HTTP/2 proxies

Tags: websocket, proxy, http2

I am developing an https http/2 proxy server as mentioned here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/docs/proxy.md#HTTPS-proxy-scheme
It is mentioned there that

> HTTPS proxies using HTTP/2 can offer better performance in Chrome than a regular HTTP proxy due to higher connection limits (HTTP/1.1 proxies in Chrome are limited to 32 simultaneous connections across all domains).

But when users try to surf a website which is using websocket over raw http connection, the response contains 'Upgrade' http header which is forbidden to be used in http/2 as there is no websockets for HTTP/2.
[https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/06/15/no-websockets-over-http2/#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20websockets%20for%20HTTP%2F2.&text=That%20spec%20details%20how%20a,connection%20into%20a%20websockets%20connection.](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/06/15/no-websockets-over-http2/#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20websockets%20for%20HTTP%2F2.&text=That%20spec%20details%20how%20a,connection%20into%20a%20websockets%20connection.)
The problem comes from the fact that when http1.1 traffic passes through an https proxy which implements http/2, headers must be transferred from http1.1 to http/2. Of course when the webpage is using TLS, there is no such a problem as all traffic passes through a connection made by http 'CONNECT' method. The problem occurs when the website does not use TLS.
If there is no solution to this problem, it means that HTTPS proxies should not implement HTTP/2 protocol.

Answer (score 4):

> As there is no websockets for HTTP/2

The link you posted is old, and since then WebSocket over HTTP/2 has been specified by [RFC 8441](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8441).

The behavior of a HTTP/2 proxy is specified in [RFC 7540, section 8.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.3).

When the client communicates with the proxy using secure HTTP/2, each HTTP/2 stream is a "tunnel" to the server.

Client and proxy communicate using secure HTTP/2, and the "tunnelling" happens because each HTTP/2 stream becomes an "infinite" request with an "infinite" response, i.e. an "infinite" series of HTTP/2 `DATA` frames in both directions that carry an opaque byte array payload.

The job of the proxy is to unwrap the `DATA` frames received by the client, and forward the byte array payload to the server, perhaps re-wrapping it into an HTTP/2 `DATA` frame if the communication between proxy and server is also HTTP/2 (it may be possible to optimize away the unwrapping and re-wrapping but it may be tricky -- for example the stream numbering could be different).

When a client attempts to perform WebSocket over HTTP/2, the browser will do as specified by RFC 8441, and the proxy will receive a `CONNECT` request with a `:protocol` pseudo-header, and the proxy will have to know what to do in that case, depending on what protocol it uses to communicate with the server.

What above describes what your proxy need to support when the communication with the client is HTTP/2.

If your proxy needs to support clients that speak HTTP/1.1, then you need to implement what is required for a proxy to support HTTP/1.1 and WebSocket proxying, and it's typically not difficult: the first is just HTTP/1.1 forwarding or HTTP `CONNECT` "tunnelling", the second is WebSocket HTTP Upgrade request forwarding followed by a "tunnel" connection or even a fully fledged WebSocket proxy.

Disclaimer, I have implemented all of the above in the [Jetty Project](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).
You can use Jetty 10 or later to implement an HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, or WebSocket, both client and server (and therefore a proxy). WebSocket over HTTP/2 is supported too.

Finally, to answer your last question, it is perfectly possible to have secure proxies support HTTP/2, even in presence of WebSocket.

For example, a clear-text WebSocket connection to a server starts with an HTTP upgrade request; this request will be sent, encrypted, to the proxy which will decrypt it and forward it to the server (using any protocol the server supports -- could even be WebSocket over secure HTTP/2); the server will reply with a 101 and upgrade the connection to WebSocket; the proxy will receive the 101 from the server and upgrade to a "tunnel" or to a WebSocket proxy; the proxy encrypts the 101 response and forward it to the client; the client decrypts it and upgrades the connection to WebSocket.
At this point, the client is speaking clear-text WebSocket *to the server* through a secure connection with the proxy (the proxy sees the clear-text WebSocket communication).

Viceversa, a secure WebSocket connection to a server starts with establishing a HTTP `CONNECT` tunnel through the proxy to the server; then the client will establish the secure communication with the server; then it will send the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket to the server (through the proxy tunnel).
At this point, the client is speaking secure WebSocket *to the server* through a secure connection with the proxy (the proxy cannot see the WebSocket communication).

The HTTP/2 variants are similar, just taking into account the HTTP/2 specific ways of "tunnelling" and transporting WebSocket.

Comment: When using an HTTP/2 proxy, the CONNECT method is used by browsers only when the target site uses 'https'. But when target site is 'http', google chrome and firefox do no use CONNECT method, instead they translate some HTTP1 headers to HTTP/2. Of course most of the websites are nowadays using HTTPS and there would be no problem with those websites when surfed using HTTP/2 proxy.